# How to get Row data after a button click in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

can anyone help me on how to get a single row data on a click event.

This is the table which is dynamically populated after Success function in AJAX call is executed

```
<div class="table-responsive table-wrap tableFixHead container-fluid">
<table class="table bg-violet dT-contain" id="datatable" >
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Main</th>
            <th>Shrinked</th>
            <th>Clicks</th>
            <th>Disable</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="bg-violet">

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="scripts/dashboard.js" defer></script>
```

This is my ajax success function

```
success: function(data){
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
        data: data,
        "autoWidth": true,
        columns: [
            {'data': 'id'},
            {'data': 'main'},
            {'data': 'shrinked'},
            {'data': 'clicks'},
            {"defaultContent": "<button id='del-btn'>Delete</button>"}
            ]
        })
    }
```

I am adding a delete button to each row dynamically, but can't seem to fetch row data using it.
I tried this method with some tweaks to my success function

```
$('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    alert( data[0] );
} );
```

But this didn't seem to work.

The JSON data returning from the AJAX call is in this format:

```
[{"id":"12","main":"ndkekfnq" ...}, {.....}]
```

I also added an onclick function on the delete button to try to fetch data but that also didn't work.

EDIT: whole AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "email": window.email,
        "token": window.token
    },
    success: function(data){
        let table = $('#datatable').dataTable({
        data: data,
        "autoWidth": true,
        columns: [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'main'},
                {'data': 'shrinked'},
                {'data': 'clicks'},
                {"defaultContent": "<button id='dis-btn' class='btn btn-warning'>Disable</button>"},
                {"defaultContent": "<button id='del-btn' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>"}
            ]
        })
        $('#datatable tbody').on('click', "#del-btn", function() {
            let row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            //for row data
            console.log(table.row(row).data().id);
        });
    }
})
```

})

What would be the correct way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example ? This is not enough on what you have posted.

Comment: Added more content in the body...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use column.render instead o defaultContent and then get the data on an outside function, you need to render a button at the render of the table:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-responsive table-wrap tableFixHead container-fluid">
        <table class="table bg-violet dT-contain" id="datatable" >
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Main</th>
                    <th>Shrinked</th>
                    <th>Clicks</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="bg-violet">
        
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <script>
      $('#datatable').dataTable( {
            "data": [{'id':20,'main':'hola','shrinked':false,'clicks':2000},{'id':21,'main':'hola','shrinked':false,'clicks':283000}],
            "autoWidth": true,
            "columns": [ 
                {"data": "id"},        
                {'data': 'main'},
                {'data': 'shrinked'},
                {'data': 'clicks'},
                {"data": "id",
                    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) { 
                        return '<button data-id="'+data+'" onclick="deleteThis(event)">Delete</button>'
                        }
                }
                
             ]
        } )

function deleteThis(e){
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Haven't tried, but based on Datatables docs, this should work, let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code for you. You need to set the `datatables` in a `var`.

Use that `var table` to look for `clicked` `row` which will `$(this).parents('tr')[0]` and use `.data.id` to the clicked item `id`

I have recreated the your example and its working fine. Just set you `ajax` response to the `data`.

**Demo**

```js
//Ajax Data
var data = [{
  "id": "10",
  "main": "ndkekfnq",
  "shrinked": "ndkekfnq",
  "clicks": "ndkekfnq"
}, {
  "id": "12",
  "main": "Something",
  "shrinked": "Data",
  "clicks": "Ha"
}]

//Data Table
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [{
      'data': 'id'
    },
    {
      'data': 'main'
    },
    {
      'data': 'shrinked'
    },
    {
      'data': 'clicks'
    },
    {
      "defaultContent": "<button id='del-btn'>Delete</button>"
    }
  ]
});


$('#datatable tbody').on('click', "#del-btn", function() {
  var row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
  //for row data
  console.log(table.row(row).data().id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-BkpSL20WETFylMrcirBahHfSnY++H2O1W+UnEEO4yNIl+jI2+zowyoGJpbtk6bx97fBXf++WJHSSK2MV4ghPcg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" integrity="sha512-1k7mWiTNoyx2XtmI96o+hdjP8nn0f3Z2N4oF/9ZZRgijyV4omsKOXEnqL1gKQNPy2MTSP9rIEWGcH/CInulptA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="table-responsive table-wrap tableFixHead container-fluid">
  <table class="table bg-violet dT-contain" id="datatable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Main</th>
        <th>Shrinked</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-violet">

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i dont wanna remove the row but rather access the "id" property of the row in which the button has been clicked, any idea how to do that?

Comment: I tried, but still can't get to log or alert the id, the console.log('working') inside the delete function is working fine, but data is not being logged

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli How come its working in the snippet above As soon as i click on delete i am getting the id of the row ? Can you make sure you are using the exact code i have provided. Let me know

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli Can you make sure copy the **exact code** and Data-tables function with a `var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({})`

Comment: I have updated my original post with whole AJAX request, i am sure i am doing everything as you suggested but still its not logging the response

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli Something else is wrong if your code there on success function or DataTables not mapping the id properly. Please check or post a screenshot of everything so i can check.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, Thank you very much though, i really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

@Javier 's answer is a very good way to solve the OP's issue. Another way, if you don't want to include **id** field twice, would be like this:

```
"columns": [ 
            {"data": "id"},        
            {'data': 'main'},
            {'data': 'shrinked'},
            {'data': 'clicks'},
            {"data": null,
                "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) { 
                    return '<button data-id="' + data.id + '" onclick="deleteThis(event)">Delete</button>'
                    }
            }
         ]
```

Comment: Yeah good advice, keeps the code dry i guess. Thank you.

Comment: @ZulfiqarAli another advantage of this approach is that now with **data** you have access to **any** field in the render property, while if you specify a field in the data property, **data** will have access to **that** field **only**.